# Drag attribute lose efficacy while adding lots of targets in Extjs 6.2.0

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop, webui

We had an issue that some targets in the end of the table couldn't be dragged even if they're set as draggable objects by using Ext.js 6.2.

After check we found that if we increased the height of the table window, some targets became draggable; If decreased the height, then more targets couldn't be dragged;

Is there some attributes to solve this problem? We guess dividing several pages might fix this issue, but we would rather show them in one pages..

The code isn't convenient to show, but we use `Ext.dd.DragSource` and `Ext.dd.DropTarget` classes to create the drag target and drog zone. And other codes I think is correct;

Thanks for your help:)

Comment: can you share a fiddle to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Emm.. I don't understand what is a fiddle. But I've assigned this issue to web engineers:)